# GDB: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, tkinter, gdb

So I'm trying to debug my C code ran in Python ctypes: [gdb: break in shared library loaded by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653467/gdb-break-in-shared-library-loaded-by-python).
However, whenever I run the gdb I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'`. I know there's a lot of questions about this error: [matplotlib error - no module named tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327134/matplotlib-error-no-module-named-tkinter), and [ImportError: No module named 'Tkinter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter). I've tried the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

And it works perfectly fine when executing from Ubuntu command line: `brandon@DESKTOP-V5LTF5T:~$ python3 MainApp.py`
But it does not work when executing from gdb:
[image]
Why would it work from the terminal but not gdb?

Comment: If `gdb` could work with `tkinter`,I think the cause is that you have two different versions of  `python`.But the `gdb` would use another version of python which you didn't install `tkinter` .

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, it's possible, see the first link attached. I ran gdb with the 'python3' argument which uses python 3.6.9, to which I installed tkinter in the picture attached above

Comment: To exclude this possibility, you could try to use `which python3` in terminal to check the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed `tkinter` for your python3 installation, but you are running `python3-dbg` from GDB. Luckily, the solution is simple: install tkinter for the debugging interpreter (`python3-tk-dbg`):

```
➜  ~ python3-dbg
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
>>> 

➜  ~ sudo apt install python3-tk-dbg 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-tk-dbg
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/509 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,441 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package python3-tk-dbg:amd64.
(Reading database ... 205251 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-tk-dbg_3.6.9-1~18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-tk-dbg:amd64 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
Setting up python3-tk-dbg:amd64 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...

➜  ~ python3-dbg
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

I face same error.Upgrade Your Python Version.I hope That work for you